# Is there any way to tell my tablet to ignore pixel density?

Tags: settings, screen

The pixel density of my tablet is 166.66666... (infinite 6) ppi.

It has a pixel density much higher than my PC and should read perfectly, but reading is a pain because the pixels that are set by software are different to those in the hardware, so the letters are sometimes crisp, sometimes have a shadow on the left, sometimes on the right and sometimes they are split between two pixels.

I have seen there are apps to change the pixel density, but I doubt this would solve the problem because the pixel density is not an integer, and these apps will probably not accept 500/3 as the pixel density.

I have seen that 2X Client (a remote desktop app) can connect to my computer and (apparently) ignore the pixel density, displaying 1024x768 pixels of my remote desktop in 1024x768 pixels of the screen of my tablet, everything looks perfectly crisp in the tablet (as much as in the PC) because of this.

I would like all apps to work in the same way and to ignore pixel density, this would use the screen in the best possible way, everything would be crisp, etc. I don't mind if letters like "i" are only one pixel width, I'm used to that in my computer and that would be just perfect for the tablet.

PD: a test for your android device, look at this:

||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||‌|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||‌||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||

(or better, check the comment with this text, the smaller font helps to see the difference). They should all look the same. In your computer you will be able to see they are all one pixel width and they all look the same. On your android device you may notice small differences between them. If you use a program that ignores the pixel density settings (like I'm guessing 2X Client does) then they should all look equal and perfectly on your android device, except maybe quite small.

I personally don't care if they look small, I'd like that. That's the point of the question.

Comment: If you are rooted there is Wanam Xposed, which has a module called 'app' settings which allows you to set the DPI per application. Or to set all to a default (usually 240 dpi to allow all apps to be available on the Play Store). If you aren't rooted I'm not sure what your options are, I'd be interested to find out.

Comment: @RossC Thank you. I am not rooted, I could consider being rooted, but even if I changed the DPI globally or per application that would solve nothing because the pixels defined by software (e.g. for letters) would not match those in the hardware, AFAIK.

Comment: That's a good point, I've had the issue with an Android TV device (resloved by throwing it in the bin and using my PC). I tried the DPI and it only DRAWS at a different one to the phone screen, I think you're right it won't solve anything for this issue. The same is apparent on the Nexus tablets, some apps are just upscaled horribly and look like a Super Nintendo on the bigger screen. Fragmented OS with dpi settings different on ever single device is not helping. I'll keep looking for a solution.

Comment: What tablet is this? If it's upscaling the screen, that's a system integration problem and can probably only be fixed by the manufacturer.

Comment: @DanHulme upscaling? the brand is unusual, but it doesn't seem to be a system integration problem, the same happens to a lesser extent with my LG phone. My guess is that this happens with every android device, look at this: |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| they should be one pixel width each and all should look the same, does that happen on your android device? Check the difference with your computer.

Comment: Is this happening only in your browser, or in any app?

Comment: @DanHulme so far this happens to me with all apps except remote desktop. You can also try to send yourself an email with the text I've put before, you can check the snippet, the subject and the body of the mail. I think that text is fairly good to test the rendering.

Comment: Using the email client won't help narrow the problem down: it uses a `WebView` to draw emails on the screen, which means it uses the same font renderer as your system's web browser (or Chrome).

Comment: @DanHulme this may help: I tried to convert this page to pdf to check how it looks in my tablet and my phone and (before doing so) I found that it doesn't look right in my computer either (using the pdf viewer in chrome). The reason is the same, the pixels in the screen are ignored and those vertical lines are split in different ways between pixels.